# 22.04 upgrade stuck on extracting jammy.tar.gz

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, tar, extract

upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04. Ran these commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo update-manager -d
```

This is what is showing on screen:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release

authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg'

extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'

None
```

It has been stuck on the 'extracting' operation for 3 hours. And the word 'None' doesn't look good to me...

What should I do?

Comment: Using the option to stream multiple commands and -y to hide prompts can hide errors. Personally I would never use them. There may have been issues before the upgrade started.

Comment: OK, my bad.  I'll bear that in mind for next time.  But right now, it's still hanging:  should I just kill the extraction process with Ctrl+C?

Comment: Sorry but I think the only thing you can do is a fresh install.

Comment: Nothing I can do with my 20.04 backup?

Comment: No idea do not know what you backed up or how. If you want Ubuntu 22.04 why not just install it? If you can restore 20.04 will you not still want to upgrade and it may happen again as there is no clue from your info what may have gone wrong.

Comment: If I install 22.04 from a thumbdrive, will it take account of all my existing personal data?

Comment: Maybe you should make a back up first. Use the try option mount the existing partition and copy to somewhere the data you need.

Comment: I did (already said so).

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe I didn't provide enough information; but it appears that nobody knows why the extraction phase would give the response "None", then hang.

On the plus side, I had done a full backup of my home folder, and despite all warnings to the contrary the system still reboots to 20.04. I don't pretend this is an answer, more a way to close the question.  Apologies to any moderators who have to pick this up. Please feel free to remove the entire thread.